# Plotting the power curve for a sign test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

The problem is: Let $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ be a random sample of size $n=10$ from a location model with median $\theta$. We wish to test $H_{0} : \theta = 72$ versus $H_{1}: θ<72$ at the significance level $\alpha =7/128$. Find the critical region of the sign test(note the sample size is too small to apply the normal approximation.) Find the power curve and plot it.

I did the first part of the question and need help plotting the power curve, the power function is $\beta(\theta) = P(S(72) \leq2, \theta<72)=$ $\sum_{k=0}^n {10 \choose k}p_{\theta}^{k}(1-p_{\theta})^{25-k} $ where $S(\theta)=$ Sign Test Statistic. My issue is that I can't think of a way to determine $p_{\theta}$, in class we did one that assumed the $X_{i}$ ~ $N(0.5,1)$ so it was easily calculated but since we were told not to apply the normal approximation I'm at a loss, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To do your power curve as a function of $\theta$ you need a distributional assumption where $\theta$ is an undetermined parameter. The power curve will different for each choice of distribution and for each choice of the way $\theta$ comes in (e.g. imagine putting $\theta$ in as a scale or as a shape parameter in a gamma density). Typically you might look at a location shift (e.g. $\theta$ appearing in the location parameter in a normal or a logistic, say) or as a multiplier on the scale (e.g. on an exponential), but there's many possibilities depending on the family.

You might try writing the power function down as an integral in a few instances, so you can see what's happening.

An alternative is to do a power curve as a function of $p(\theta)$ itself; that would save having to identify a family (just assume continuity), but to use that to identify power in a specific instance would require a little work for each specific case.